# Thymeleaf: access map with variable key

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

This is my model.

```
Map <String, String>
```

e.g.

```
{ sam: "NY", tom: "SF", sue: "WN" }
```

How can I access the value from JavaScript if I have the key in a variable?

```
// mod is the model
    
var key = "sam";
var foo = [[${mod.get ("sam")}]];    // key by string -> foo is defined (OK)
var bar = [[${mod.get (key)}]];      // key by variable -> bar is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the full Java map to your JavaScript code in your Thymeleaf template:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var key = "sam";
    var mymap = [[${mod}]];
    var bar = mymap[key];
    console.log( bar );
</script>
```

Thymeleaf will create the following JavaScript (as seen in your rendered web page):

```js
var key = "sam";
var mymap = {"sue":"WN","tom":"SF","sam":"NY"};
var bar = mymap[key];
console.log( bar ); // this prints "NY" to the browser console
```

The key point here is: Thymeleaf only exists on the server - it cannot execute JavaScript commands (on the server) - and there is no variable called `key` in your model that you pass to Thymeleaf.

Therefore the `key` in the Thymeleaf expression `${mod.get (key)}` is null.

---

Another way around this is to add `"sam"` to the model *in your Java code* - for example:

```
model.put("key", "sam");
```

Or, for Spring:

```
model.addAttribute("key", "sam");
```

Now, there *is* a valid value for `key`, which can be used to evaluate the Thymeleaf expression `${mod.get (key)}` on the server.

But this does not use the JavaScript line `var key = "sam";`.

This option may not be possible - it depends on where the value `"sam"` originates. If it's not available to your Java code, this is obviously not going to help you.

---

Reference: See [Advanced inlined evaluation and JavaScript serialization](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#advanced-inlined-evaluation-and-javascript-serialization) for more details.